# Вопрос по парсингу сайтов

Tags: php, парсер, symfony

Здравствуйте.
У меня есть сервис, который содержит цены с разных торговых точек. Сейчас приходится самому обновлять цены, это занимает очень много времени. По этому хочу написать парсер. Он будит работать примерно так: указываем ссылку на товар, и класс / ид тега,в котором находится цена. Скрипт запускается и парсит цену с сайта. Хочу использовать file_get_contents() + symfony DomCrawler.
Сам вопрос: так как у всех сайтов, своя верстка, подойдет ли решение которое я написал выше для парсинга разных сайтов, или есть более лучшее решение?

Comment: а владельцы торговых точек вкурсе что Вы используете их цены? Если да, то лучше с ними договориться о выгрузке цен с их стороны. Ведь парсить сайт накладно по ресурсам. Ежедневные запросы ко всем страницам сайта это маленькая ддос атака. Да и если на каждом сайте по несколько десятков тысяч страниц то обновление несколько часов может длиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если парсинг с одного сайта, то лучше использовать регулярные выражения. Если сайтов несколько, то очень рекомендую десктопную программу Content Downloader. Она имеет очень гибкие настройки с внедрением PHP, записью напрямую в MySQL и заливкой на FTP. 
Не совсем понятно с описания как вы собираетесь указывать ссылку на товар. Единожды в карточке Вашего агрегатора или непосредственно во время парсинга? Какие задачи перед Вашей системой?

Comment: Незнаю как по другому обьяснить) вот структуда бд: товары | продавци |  связующая таблица (ид товара, ид продавца, цена продавца, ссылка на сайт продавца). Сейчас я делую так: выбираю товар, выбираю продовца, назначаю цену, и указываю ссылку на сайт продавца. А хотелось бы сделать так,  Выбираю продовца (у него вже есть цены и ссылки на карточки товаров на его сайте), запускаю парсер, и он бегает по ссылкам и парсит цены. Как то так

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents('link_donor');
$pattern = 'регулярное выражение поиска кода цены';
preg_match($pattern, $content, $out);`  В out будет значение. Может придется почистить от обрамляющих тегов, по которым велся поиск

Answer (score 1):

Я бы порекомендовал использовать `scrapy`, это конечно python, а не php, но на php такого рода парсеры и не пишут. Вот можно почитать про него [Собираем данные с помощью Scrapy](https://habrahabr.ru/post/115710/).
Очень удобная и гибкая вещь, парсит асинхронно в несколько потоков. Можете почитать более подробно по ссылке или на официальном сайте.

И второй вариант, это использовать, что-нибудь вроде `PhantomJs` или `SlimerJs` [Простой парсинг сайтов с помощью SlimerJS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247847/). Если первый вариант не подойдет, по каким либо причинам.

Answer (score 0):

Я для таких целей использовал [Grab::Spider](http://docs.grablib.org/en/latest/spider/intro.html), это на языке Python. 
Есть русская документация, примеры можно найти на Хабре. 
Сами запросы делал через XPath, модуль FirePHP для Firefox в помощь, ну или можно через CSS запросы, но мне кажется это менее эффективно.
Полученные таким способом данные можно заливать в любую БД, благо у python библиотек много.